# How can I see the browsing history and bookmarks in the stock browser?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, browser

I have an SGS with Froyo.  I can't seem to find the browsing history in the stock browser.  I'm also only able to access bookmarks (or favorites, or shortcuts) from inside the browser.

How can they be accessed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my Samsung Fascinate I click on this button next to the address bar:

[image]

And it takes me to this screen, which also has a History tab (top-right):

[image]

The functionality shown above is also available to me on CyanogenMod 7, leading me to think that it's a feature of the stock browser (i.e. not added by Samsung).

Answer (score 3):

Note this is "one way" to get there on a true stock android browser. Samsung, for some reason, removed the Bookmarks menu item. eldarerathis' answer will work for both Stock and the TouchWiz (Samsung) versions of the browser.

- Open the browser
- press menu key
- select bookmarks
- here are the bookmarks
- There should be a tab that is called "History"

  - You can also clear the history from that tab.

Comment: Do you use a custom ROM? The browser on my stock Samsung Fascinate doesn't work like this ("Bookmarks" is not in the menu).

Comment: I think bookmarks menu was removed in the samsung touchwiz browser.

Comment: I just looked at the froyo branch of the AOSP source code to make sure, and the Browser menu item is in the Stock browser. Samsung must have removed it from their build of the browser.

Comment: I do definitely have it in CM7 (on my EVO), but I do not on my fully stock Fascinate.

Comment: Yeah. I know its in CM7, that is what I am running on my SGS vibrant. I missed the "SGS" in the original question. But I just wanted to check AOSP to make sure the menu wasn't something that was added to CM7.

Answer (score 0):

My browser history was at the bottom right of the screen.looked like the bookmark with a star. I think i deleted it by opening the settings where the 3 vertical dots is by the address bar.  My phone says Galaxy prevail LTE on the back

Comment: This sounds like you are using Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Hi    I don't know what version of android or Samsung internet browser you use but on my phone galaxy A7 I found this

[image: First] and [image: then]